# Package's namespace polluted by Django?

Tags: python, django

*Django 1.8*

For no obvious reasons, global variable defined in package's module is replaced between its initial assignment and deferred function call.

Minimal Django project is created with `django-admin startproject`. New empty application added with `django-admin startapp simplelib`. New app `simplelib` added to `INSTALLED_APPS` of project's `settings.py`.

Bellow is the only added code:

```
# content of myproject.simplelib.__init__.py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import class_prepared


def myhandler(sender, **kwargs):
    print 'models from myhandler: {}'.format(models)


def direct_call():
    print 'models from direct_call: {}'.format(models)


class_prepared.connect(myhandler)

print 'models from top namespace: {}'.format(models)

direct_call()
```

When project is run with `manage.py runserver`, following output is produced:

```
models from top namespace: <module 'django.db.models' from '/home/<snip>/Projects/Python/django-projects/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/__init__.pyc'>
models from direct_all: <module 'django.db.models' from '/home/<snip>/Projects/Python/django-projects/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/__init__.pyc'>
models from myhandler: <module 'simplelib.models' from '/home/<snip>/Projects/Python/django-projects/myproject/simplelib/models.pyc'>
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See, when signal handler function is invoked, `modules` global variable is changed.
There is no other project's code. It has to be altered by Django itself.

Note: above described effect applies only when `simplelib` is placed at the start of `INSTALLED_APPS` tuple. When added at the end, `models` still points to `django.db.models`, as expected.

Any idea what's going here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal Python behaviour.

When you import a submodule, that submodule is set as an attribute on the parent module. In this case, when `simplelib.models` is imported, the `models` submodule is set on the parent module `simplelib`. The parent module namespace is the same as that module's `__init__.py` global namespace. This will overwrite the old value.

If you put `simplelib` as the first entry in `INSTALLED_APPS`, its `models` submodule will be the first models module imported by Django. This will replace the `simplelib.models` attribute before any model fires the `class_prepared` signal. On the other hand, if you put `simplelib` at the end of `INSTALLED_APPS`, Django will load `simpellib.models` as the last models module. Any models that are imported before that will fire the `class_prepared` signal before `simplelib.models` is imported, and before the `models` attribute is replaced with the submodule.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I had to miss this gotcha in documentation.